# how to change the value of an array to 0 when the user enters the same value (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, multidimensional-array

My goal for this code is for it to show the current seat numbers, take the seat number to reserve from the user, set that seat number value to 0, then print it back to the user and make the code loop. I am now stuck at displaying when the seat is taken. once two or more seats have been reserved, it prints more seat is taken messages.

Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "_pause.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int s[5][7] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
        {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21},
        {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28},
        {29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35}
    };
    int i, j, k, l, m;


do {
        cout << "Seats Available:" << endl;
        cout << endl;
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                    cout << s[i][j] << "\t";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
                cout << "Enter Seat Number: ";
                cin >> s[i][j];
                cout << endl;
                m - 1;
                if (s[i][j] > 35){
                    cout << "Error, Invalid Seat number." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                } else {
                    for (k = 0; k < i; k++){
                        for (l = 0; l < j; l++){
                            if (s[i][j] == s[k][l]){
                                s[k][l] = 0;
                                cout << "Seat Successfully Reserved." << endl;
                                cout << endl;
                            } else if (s[k][l] == 0){
                                cout << "Seat Taken." << endl;
                                cout << endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    } while (m > 1);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your current program has *undefined behavior* since you're going out of bound when you wrote: `cin >> s[i][j];` since at this point `i=5` and `j=7` and indices start from `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Use a separate variable for the user input, don't store it in your array.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `cin >> s[i][j];` after the loop will make your program have *undefined behavior* since it writes out of bounds and you should use a separate variable for the input.

A correction of both could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// Define constants with names instead of using 5 and 7 everywhere:
constexpr unsigned Rows = 5;
constexpr unsigned Cols = 7;

// A helper function to print the seats
void print_seats(const int (&seats)[Rows][Cols]) {
    for(auto& row : seats) {
        for(int col : row) {
            std::cout << col << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int s[Rows][Cols] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
                         {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
                         {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21},
                         {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28},
                         {29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35}};

    std::cout << "Seats Available:\n";
    print_seats(s); // Use the helper function

    std::cout << "Enter Seat Number: ";
    
    // Declare a separate variable for the input. It's an `unsigned int` here
    // to only be allowed to hold positive integers (including 0).
    unsigned seat;                         

    if(std::cin >> seat) {                 // check that input succeeds
        --seat;                            // make it 0-based(*)

        if(seat >= Rows * Cols) {          // check that it's within the allowed range
            std::cout << "invalid seat\n";

        } else {                           // the user entered a valid seat number
            unsigned row = seat / Cols;    // convert seat to row
            unsigned col = seat % Cols;    // convert seat to column
            s[row][col] = 0;               // set it to 0
            print_seats(s);                // print seats again
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>`*`</sup> - If the user enters 0, an `unsigned` like `seat` will wrap around when doing `--seat` to become a positive value. `-1` will for example become the largest value an `unsigned int` can hold which will be much larger than `Rows * Cols`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <array>


static constexpr std::size_t rowCount { 5 };
static constexpr std::size_t colCount { 7 };


consteval auto initializeSeats( )
{
    std::array< std::array<std::size_t, colCount>, rowCount> seats;

    std::size_t idx { };

    for ( auto& row : seats )
    {
        for ( auto& col : row )
        {
            col = ++idx;
        }
    }

    return seats;
}

void printSeats( const std::array< std::array<std::size_t, colCount>, rowCount>& seats )
{
    std::cout << "Seats Available:" << '\n';

    for ( const auto& row : seats )
    {
        for ( const auto& col : row )
        {
            std::cout << col << '\t';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

std::pair<bool, bool> reserveSeat( std::array< std::array<std::size_t, colCount>, rowCount>& seats )
{
    std::cout << "Enter the Seat Number: ";
    std::string selectedSeat { };
    std::cin >> selectedSeat;
    const std::size_t seatNum { std::stoull( selectedSeat ) };

    if ( seatNum < 1 || seatNum > 35 )
    {
        return std::pair<bool, bool>( false, false );
    }

    for ( auto& row : seats )
    {
        for ( auto& col : row )
        {
            if ( col == seatNum )
            {
                col = 0;
                return std::pair<bool, bool>( true, true );
            }
        }
    }

    return std::pair<bool, bool>( true, false );
}

void printReservationMsg( const std::pair<bool, bool> statusOfReservation )
{
    ( std::get<0>( statusOfReservation ) ) ? std::cout << "" :
                                             std::cout << "Error, Invalid Seat Number.\n";

    if ( std::get<0>( statusOfReservation ) )
    {
        ( std::get<1>( statusOfReservation ) ) ? std::cout << "Seat Successfully Reserved!\n" :
                                                 std::cout << "Seat Previously Taken!\n";
    }
}

int main( )
{
    std::array< std::array<std::size_t, colCount>, rowCount> seats { initializeSeats( ) };

    char isExiting { };

    do
    {
        printSeats( seats );

        const auto [ isNumberValid, isReserveSuccessful ] { reserveSeat( seats ) };

        printReservationMsg( { isNumberValid, isReserveSuccessful } );

        std::cout << "\nEnter C to continue, E to end the program: ";
        std::cin >> isExiting;
        std::cin.ignore( );

    } while ( isExiting == 'C' || isExiting == 'c' );
}
```

**Note**: The above code only compiles with C++20. You need to enable the *C++20* option in your compiler in order to compile it.

**Sample input/output:**

```
Seats Available:
1       2       3       4       5       6       7
8       9       10      11      12      13      14
15      16      17      18      19      20      21
22      23      24      25      26      27      28
29      30      31      32      33      34      35
Enter the Seat Number: 36
Error, Invalid Seat Number.

Enter C to continue, E to end the program: c
Seats Available:
1       2       3       4       5       6       7
8       9       10      11      12      13      14
15      16      17      18      19      20      21
22      23      24      25      26      27      28
29      30      31      32      33      34      35
Enter the Seat Number: 3
Seat Successfully Reserved!

Enter C to continue, E to end the program: C
Seats Available:
1       2       0       4       5       6       7
8       9       10      11      12      13      14
15      16      17      18      19      20      21
22      23      24      25      26      27      28
29      30      31      32      33      34      35
Enter the Seat Number: 3
Seat Previously Taken!

Enter C to continue, E to end the program: c
Seats Available:
1       2       0       4       5       6       7
8       9       10      11      12      13      14
15      16      17      18      19      20      21
22      23      24      25      26      27      28
29      30      31      32      33      34      35
Enter the Seat Number: -1234
Error, Invalid Seat Number.

Enter C to continue, E to end the program: c
Seats Available:
1       2       0       4       5       6       7
8       9       10      11      12      13      14
15      16      17      18      19      20      21
22      23      24      25      26      27      28
29      30      31      32      33      34      35
Enter the Seat Number: 35
Seat Successfully Reserved!

Enter C to continue, E to end the program: e
```

Comment: @Jai Check the updated answer and its sample input/output. It does all the things you want. If you don't have access to a C++20 compiler then try to install one. Otherwise, just remove the `consteval` keyword from `consteval auto initializeSeats( )`, and then it should compile successfully.